# Should I dynamic cast or not

Tags: c++, polymorphism

My problem is this, I have a base class from which classes are derived. I have an overloaded += operator in the base class but I only want to be able to add derived classes of the same type. I do this by returning the lhs and producing a warning message if they are not the same type.

```
class base{
   int variable;
   public:
   base(int v);
   base & operator+=(const base & rhs);

class a: public base{
}

class b: public base{
}

base & operator+=(const base & rhs){
if(type_same(const & rhs){
    variable+=rhs.variable; }
return *this
}

a first(1);
a second(5);
b third(2);

first+=second // first.variable now =6
second+=third // warning produced second.variable still = 5
```

I've never used dynamic cast before so my question is is it possible/advisable to a check using it and typeid to find out whether the types passed are the same. My alternative is a string constant name for each derived class.

Comment: huh - the code is a big syntax error as presented. Also, `type_same` is defined _where_? Lastly, it seems like a very bad idea to silently emit warnings on programming errors (like mismatched types). Throw a runtime_error instead?

Comment: It's just psuedo code to try and make my question as clear as possible. It was easier than copying and pasting all the different little relevant bits from my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take: you could employ CRTP

The below code will issue the type mismatch error at compile time, as suggested by others.

```
template <typename Derived>
class base{
   int variable;
 public:
   base(int v) { variable = v; }
   Derived& operator+=(const Derived& rhs);
};

struct a: base<a> {
    a(int v): base<a>(v) {}
};

struct b: base<b> {
    b(int v): base<b>(v) {}
};

template <typename Derived> 
Derived& base<Derived>::operator+=(const Derived& rhs) 
{
    variable += rhs.variable; 
    return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    a a1(1), a2(2);
    b b1(1), b2(2);

    a1 += a2;
    b1 += a2; // compile time error :)

    return 0;
}
```

Even if you really wanted to type the operator arguments as `base&` you'd at least gain the benefit of using `static_cast<>` because the conversion is exact and well defined at runtime. I can expand the idea in a few

Comment: Yum, templates, that's the bit that was missing. Thanks.

Comment: CRPT also means that all the classes are now derived from a different base. I don't understand how this can be the solution, given that there was actual reason to use inheritance in the first place.

Comment: @UncleBens: that's what I didn't assume there. Also, making this polymorphic was addressed (giving the rationale `Even if you really wanted to type the operator arguments as base& you'd at least gain the benefit of using static_cast<>`)

Answer (score 4):

Why have the operator+ in the base class in the first place? If you just place `operator+` with the correct type into the `a` and `b` class, it will work, without any `dynamic_cast`.

`dynamic_cast` is usually a hint that your types are not well designed and should be avoided. In the described scenario, you can surely get by without any `dynamic_cast`. If not, then `a` and `b` should not be derived from `base`, as they do behave differently. Think about it from the user perspective: By deriving `a` from `base`, you tell the user that `a` can be used as `base`. If a method requires the actual type, move it down instead of putting it into the base interface.

The correct usage btw. would be to `dynamic_cast` the rhs to the current type (i.e. `dynamic_cast<b*>(&rhs)`) and if that returns a non-zero value, then `rhs` was indeed of the correct type (however, think about what happens if there is a class derived from `b` being passed in!)

Comment: I want to keep it in my base class as this is just an example and my actual version does some additional checks and things making it longer and I'll have about 10 derived classes, I figured given the operation is exactly the same for all of them it'd be best in the base class. I just want the condition that the different types cant be added. With the dynamic cast version I presume I would have to iterate through a list of potentially correct dynamic casts till I hit my no zero one.

Comment: It seems to me that the "here's something in the base class, but it has additional requirements when you call it" violates the Liskov Substitution Principle.  Of course, the LSP isn't an eternal truth, but simply something that has turned out to flag potentially troubling code.  As such, the design should give you pause.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem that you stated in your post, `dynamic_cast` and RTTI are definitely the right tools. However, issuing a warning at **runtime** while providing **compile-time** support for a **'+'** operation may point to issues in the design where the users of your API would not expect exactly the behavior that your API provides.